# In VB.NET does contextstrip.tag = dgv act as a pointer or a copy?

Tags: .net, vb.net, pointers, memory

In VB.NET does

```
Dim dgv as new datagridview
contextstrip.tag = dgv
```

act as a pointer or a copy?

I am using it to pass the controlling DGV to the Context Menus dropdownitems because of the issues with .SourceControl. How inefficient is this?

Comment: Well, it looks quite easy to tell through a simple test... did you try ?

Comment: As it is now it is a pointer to a null object. (Well a reference to) Remember to instantiate your grid before and not after the assignement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works as a pointer, not as a copy.  The way you can tell is the type of the object.  In other languages like C, you can reference any object in either way because it is determined by the way you define your variables.  In .NET, however, it is determined by the type of the object itself.  The designers of .NET decided that, for the sake of simplicity, if you want to reference something as a pointer, you'll probably *always* want to reference it as a pointer, and vice versa.

[Reference Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t63sy5hs.aspx) (classes) are objects which are always created on the heap and referenced by pointer.  Value Types (structures) are always created on the stack and variables contain the data directly rather than a pointer to the data.  Since the [`DataGridView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is declared as a `Class`, it is a reference type.  Therefore, any variable that is set to a `DataGridView` object will contain a pointer, not a copy.  If you really do need to make a copy, you would need to look into cloning or serialization.

On a side note, value type objects can be placed on the heap too through a process called [*Boxing*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx).  Since the `Tag` property is declared as `Object`, if you were to set it to a value type object, the object would be boxed first.